# Can not create new thread using python multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to work with two huge lists using the multiprocessing module of python.To share the data between these processes a `manager.dict()` object. Here is a code snippet.

```
def my_function(item, list_two, return_dict):
    for val in list_two:
        # Do some I/O operation and DB connect operations and 
        # get modified values of variables item and val
        new_value = item + val
        return_dict[item] = new_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    procs = []
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    return_dict = manager.dict()
    list_one = [1, 2, 3, 5.....]  # len(list_one) = 120
    list_two = ['a', 'b', 'c', .......]  # len(list_two) = 800
    for item in list_one:
        proc = Process(target=my_function, args=(str(item), list_two, return_dict))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
    print(return_dict)
```

Now since I am using `Process` object it creates processes equal to the number of items in my list_one and joins them.
I execute this program and meanwhile, I execute `top` command to see that there are about 80 users logged in.
But as soon as the number of users increases say 125, the same program breaks saying that `error: can't start new thread`.

```
multiprocessing.cpu_count() = 16
```

I even tried to break `list_one` into batches of 10 and execute for those batches. But unfortunately, it is processing the first batch only. It doesn't work on remaining batches.

So, why is the program breaking, is it because it cannot create so many threads as there are more users or because it cannot perform these many I/O operations parallelly?

Using Python Version - 2.6

EDIT: Posting Traceback

```
Process SyncManager-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 525, in _run_server
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 158, in serve_forever
    t.start()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 474, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
error: can't start new thread
Process Process-104:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
Process Process-25:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 81, in my_function
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 81, in my_function
Process Process-101:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 81, in my_function
Process Process-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 81, in my_function
    output = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1144, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
    output = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1144, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
    output = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1144, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
    output = subprocess.Popen(args_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1144, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
Process Process-53:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
Process Process-30:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
Process Process-19:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 726, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
Process Process-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 726, in _callmethod
Process Process-47:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
Process Process-75:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    kind, result = conn.recv()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 726, in _callmethod
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    kind, result = conn.recv()
IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 726, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 726, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 726, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
IOError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
Process Process-35:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-114:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-84:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-98:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-102:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
Process Process-110:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-87:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-74:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
Process Process-36:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
Process Process-69:
    self.run()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
Process Process-77:
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
Traceback (most recent call last):
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-111:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-80:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-112:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
Process Process-52:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-83:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
Process Process-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-64:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
Process Process-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
Process Process-62:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-73:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-61:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
Process Process-5:
Process Process-60:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
Process Process-37:
Process Process-48:
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 119, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    proc_name, ret_version, ret_s_version]
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-108:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./test_multiprocess.py", line 137, in my_function
    proc_name, ret_version, 'Object Missing']
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 725, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
```

Comment: Small correction - you are not creating new *threads*, you are creating new *processes*. They are significantly different things so shouldn't be confused.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of the error?

Comment: If I run the code above (adding in the needed imports and setting the two lists up as a list of numbers, the code seems to work fine. When you say "two huge lists", what exactly do you mean. From the code you've shown, they don't look huge...

Comment: If you are hitting a kernel limit with your number of subprocesses, could you instead use `multiprocessing.Pool()` with a set number of workers and map_async your tasks to the pool? Then you would be in control of the number of workers, which is a sensible idea anyway.

Comment: Interesting. See my other comment about the hugeness of the lists. Is there anything else that could be using a lot of threads? Try something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/88972/how-to-get-from-terminal-total-number-of-threads-per-process-and-total-for-al to see how many threads are already running. Is it possible you have something at the OS level that's limiting how many threads your processes can spawn?

Comment: @TomDalton Yeah that's my bad with processes/threads. 
Also, I have tried to include as much of traceback I could.
The list `list_one` is from test environment. When prod environment comes into picture the length of that list will be around 1300. So there will be 1300 processes then. Isn't that huge considering its failing when the list length is 120 only?

Comment: @Hannu When I use a `Pool` object it creates only 16 processes (as cpu_count =16) which ultimately takes a lot of time and thats the whole purpose of my script reduce time consumption.

Comment: Then create more of them with pool. You can set the number as a parameter at pool creation `foo = Pool(42)` will give you 42 workers.  I think it is a good idea to be in control of how many processes you create instead of letting a list of unknown length determine that. You will also find there is a sweet spot somewhere where you do not gain more performance anymore even when adding more processes, and there is no reason whatsoever to go beyond that.

Comment: Running 120 subprocesses might not be optimal in terms of speed, but it shouldn't cause the error that's being described, so I think that's a bit of a red herring. Can try stripping your code back so it's essentially launching 120 subprocesses with the manager and passing the big list? And then start halving the list size to see if you can launch N subprocesses successfully. And then see if N > 0 or 1.

Comment: @TomDalton Using the link that you have provided. 
NLWP count is 6 until the program stops
Count of already running threads is 1451.

Comment: I'd start trying to debug this by gradually reducing the size of things to see if you can get the multiprocessing/manager stuff working for maybe 2 subprocesses, passing a small amount of data to them. Then work back up to the sizes you're dealing with. That will give you some more information to work with about what's actually happening here. When you say "two huge lists", what exactly do you mean. From the code you've shown, they don't look huge...

Comment: Finally, after some testing & debugging I have come to these conclusions
1 When I create a list of length 1500 nos & pass that to a simple square function it is able to create those many processes. So the list is not huge as @TomDalton you have been mentioning.
2 When I introduced a sleep(3) in that square function, it breaks again stating can't create new thread. So the I/O & DB operations which I have been performing in my original function should be brought down to 3 seconds or less for my script to work.
3 The I/O & DB operation take about 60 secs to perform all the required processing.

Comment: @TomDalton Also, the working size of the list `list_one` is approx. 100. Anything beyond that breaks.


@Hannu I am yet to find that sweet spot, when I use Pool(120) it creates 120 Processes so then how come Process object is unable to create 120 processes?

Comment: Whatever the "Do some I/O operation and DB connect operations" are, I assume when you run lots of them in parallel then you hit some system constraint on the number of threads you're using. Without seeing that code it's hard to say much more.